# Finding integral over inconvenient set

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Put $F = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : |x^2-y^2| \leq 1, 2|xy| \leq 1 \}$. How do we find the following integral?

$$\int_F (x^2 + y^2) \,d(x,y)$$

I'm sure we need to use Jacobi's transformation theorem to get rid of that $F$ in the integral. But I can't see how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HINT**: Consider the change of variables $u=x^2-y^2$, $v=xy$.

Elaborating:

By symmetry, we get $4$ times the integral over the region $S=\{(x,y): x,y\ge 0,\ -1\le x^2-y^2\le 1,\ xy\le 1/2\}$. Consider  $R=\{(u,v): -1\le u\le 1,\ 0\le v\le 1/2\}$ and $g\colon R\to S$, where $g^{-1}(x,y) = (x^2-y^2,xy) = (u,v)$. Note that $\det(Dg^{-1})(x,y) = 2(x^2+y^2)$.

Let $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$. Then the Change of Variables Theorem gives us
\begin{align*}
\int_S f(x,y)\,dx\,dy &= \int_R f\circ g(u,v)|\det Dg(u,v)|\,du\,dv \\
&= \int_R \left(f\cdot \frac1{|\det (Dg^{-1})|}\right)\circ g(u,v)\,du\,dv \\
&= \int_R \frac 12\,du\,dv = \frac12\int_0^{1/2}\int_{-1}^1 du\,dv = \frac12.
\end{align*}
Thus, the final answer is $4\cdot\dfrac12 = 2$.

Answer (score 2):

Let we set $x=\rho\cos\theta$ and $y=\rho\sin\theta$. The first condition translates into $|\cos 2\theta|\leq\frac{1}{\rho^2}$, the second one into $|\sin(2\theta)|\leq\frac{1}{\rho^2}$. If we fix $\rho>0$, the Lebesgue measure of the set:
$$ E_{\rho}=\left\{\theta\in[0,2\pi): \max(|\cos(2\theta)|,|\sin(2\theta)|)\leq\frac{1}{\rho^2}\right\} $$
is $2\pi$ if $\rho\leq 1$, $0$ if $\rho\geq 2^{1/4}$ and
$$ -2\pi+8\arcsin\frac{1}{\rho^2} $$
if $\rho\in[1,2^{1/4}]$. Our integral equals:
$$\begin{eqnarray*} I=\int_{0}^{2^{1/4}} \rho^3 \mu(E_\rho)\,d\rho&=&2\pi\int_{0}^{1}\rho^3\,d\rho-2\pi\int_{1}^{2^{1/4}}\rho^3\,d\rho+8\int_{1}^{2^{1/4}}\rho^3\arcsin\frac{1}{\rho^2}\,d\rho\\&=&\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{2}+2=\color{red}{2}.\end{eqnarray*}$$

Comment: are you sure this answer is correct?

Comment: @iwriteonbananas: quite. Have you spotted something wrong?

Comment: hmm, can you elaborate on why $E_\rho$ has Lebesgue measure $0$ if $\rho \geq 2^{1/4}$ and why it has Lebesgue measure $2\pi-8\arcsin\frac{1}{\rho^2}$ if $\rho \in [1, 2^{1/4}]$ ?

Comment: @iwriteonbananas: Since $\cos^2(2\theta)+\sin^2(2\theta)=1$, $\cos(2\theta)$ and $\sin(2\theta)$ cannot both have absolute value less than $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$, so the set $E_\rho$ is empty for $\rho>2^{1/4}$.

Comment: Also regarding the integrals: why do you have $\rho^3?$ shouldnt it just be $\rho$?

Comment: The circle of radius $\rho$ has length $2\pi\rho$ and you are integrating on it $x^2+y^2 = \rho^2$, so there is a $\rho^\color{red}{3}$.

Comment: of course. now why is $\lambda^2(E_{\rho}) = 2\pi-8\arcsin\frac{1}{\rho^2}$ for $\rho \in [1, 2^{1/4}]$?

Comment: @iwriteonbananas: For which angles $\theta$ the absolute value of $\sin(2\theta)$ or the absolute value of $\cos(2\theta)$ is too big (bigger than $\frac{1}{\rho^2}$)?

Comment: sorry, i'm not sure how to find that out. i guess the angle would need to be bigger than $\frac{1}{2} \arcsin(1/\rho^2)$ and $\frac{1}{2} \arccos(1/\rho^2)$

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Mathematica seems to believe that the answer is 2

Comment: @KevinDriscoll: are you sure you integrated $x^2+y^2$ over the given region and not just $1$ ?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Yes, I used: A = ImplicitRegion[Abs[x^2 - y^2] <= 1 && 2 Abs[x y] <= 1, {x, y}]; and Integrate[x^2 + y^2, {x, y} \[Element] A]

Comment: Ok, so probably $\mu(E_\rho)$ is not what I wrote here, but the procedure is right. I will fix this soon.

Comment: @KevinDriscoll: Ok, mistake spotted, now everything's right.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Okay, thanks. Now I just have to figure out why we keep coming up with 1 and not 2.

Comment: $1$ is too few, the integral over the unit disk is $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and our region includes the unit disk.